# Djangos TEMPLATE_DIRS not found

Tags: python, django, templates

I am trying to create a login page in my django application. I created a "templates" folder on the root directory of my application.

Then on my settings.py I wrote this code.

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),)

And it is giving this feedback:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/
>   Template-loader postmortem
>
> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
>   Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
>   Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
>   /Users/julianasakae/Desktop/DjangoProject/demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/login.html (File does not exist)
>   /Users/julianasakae/Desktop/DjangoProject/demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/login.html (File does not exist)
>   /Users/julianasakae/Desktop/DjangoProject/boardgames/main/templates/login.html (File does not exist)

I tryed everything, it does not seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please update your question and add the complete error message.

Comment: add    `print TEMPLATE_DIRS`   right after the line of the setting and run your server to see where it points to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Django are you using? It appears that `TEMPLATE_DIRS` was used prior to 1.8 but in the current version it has changed to a `DIRS` option in the `TEMPLATES` setting.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            '/home/html/templates/lawrence.com',
            '/home/html/templates/default',
        ],
    },
]
```

[Template DIRS Option Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#the-dirs-option)

Comment: Great job. It was a version problem. Thank you very much. You saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not a good solution, but try hardcoding the full path.